# Invalid image from android_tutorial_camera?

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I have the latest code for rosjava and the android rosjava.  But my ubuntu laptop will not display an image from the /camera/image_raw topic.  I even tried changing the topic to /camera/image_raw/compressed.  I have tried various ways of invoking image_view on the laptop but it always displays a blank window.  I know the phone is sending images because I can view then using the android_image_transport app on another phone when all of them are tied to the same ubuntu ros master.  I cannot rosbag the image topics from the android_tutorial_camera app either.  The bag is empty/corrupted.  Help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11428/invalid-image-from-android_tutorial_camera?/) by [Nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1162/nathan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Copying from the comment:

Looking at the terminal running roscore, I saw I was victim of using my workstations hostname instead of its IP. Similar to another post in answers.ros.org, I did an "export ROS_IP='192.168.1.2'" in both terminals -- the one running roscore AND the one with image_view

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried the following in your terminal:

To print the contents of one message on screen (ctrl-C to interrupt):

```
rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/image_raw
```

To check the bandwidth used by the topic:

```
rostopic bw /camera/image_raw
```

To check the frequency of publishing:

```
rostopic hz /camera/image_raw
```

Another thing you can do, after starting image_view like this:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
```

is to open another terminal and typing

```
rxgraph
```

This should show if image_view is actually subscribing to the topic. Assuming that the previous rostopic tests revealed that data is in fact being published on the topic. As a last resort:

```
roswtf
```

If no data is being sent to the topic, there could be something wrong with the camera driver.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) with karma: 465 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-10-08**:
Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept the answer?

**Comment by [Nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1162/nathan/) on 2011-10-06**:
Thank you for the debug tips.  Looking at the terminal running roscore, I saw I was victim of using my workstations hostname instead of its IP.  Similar to another post in answers.ros.org, I did an "export ROS_IP='192.168.1.2'" in both terminals -- the one running roscore AND the one with image_view